# Conditional Properties in TypeScript Interfaces: Adding Specific Properties to a Generic Interface Based on Type Parameter

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-generics

I'm facing an issue in TypeScript where I want to conditionally add properties to a generic interface based on the type parameter. Let me provide some context and an example:

Let's say I have two interfaces A and G<T>:

```
interface A {
    IA: string;
}

interface G<T> {
    IG: string;
    Parent: T;
}
```

Now, what I'm trying to achieve is to add additional properties to G<T> specifically when it's instantiated with type A. For example, when I use G<A>, I want it to include additional properties like prop1, but when I use G<B> (where B is another type), I don't want those additional properties. Something like this:

```
inteface G<T> extends A {
    prop1: string;
}
```

I'm looking for a solution or alternative approach to achieve this conditional addition of properties based on the type parameter. Any ideas or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `type` to do that.

Here is an example

```
interface A {
  IA: string
}

type G<T> = {
  IG: string
} & T

// ok
const g: G<A> = {
  IA: 'IA',
  IG: 'IG',
}

// error 
const g: G<A> = {
  IG: 'IG',
}
```

if the prop is not from the `A`, you can do that

```
interface A {
  IA: string
}

interface B {
  IB: string
}

type G<T> = {
  IG: string
} & (T extends A ? { prop1: string } : { prop2: string })

// ok
const ga: G<A> = {
  IG: 'IG',
  prop1: 'IA',
}

// error
const gb: G<B> = {
  IG: 'IG',
  prop1: 'IA',
}
```

Comment: I cannot use type as i am extending intefaces of d.ts file of an package by using ambient modules.
I need additional properties when the combination of G<A> is present, not the property of A.

Comment: @Ram, Your question says "or alternative approach" but doesn't give your constraints, so you're going to get answers that don't work for you unless you [edit] your question to let people know what you can and can't do.  Note that if you are required to use interfaces then it is impossible; interfaces need to have statically known property keys.

Comment: @jcalz Thanks for the feedback, will try to give more details on the question. I am afraid I had to work with Interface for my scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way to set the conditional properties:

```
interface G<T> {
    IG: string;
    Parent: T;

    prop1: T extends A ? string : never;
    prop2: T extends B ? string : never;
}
```

Using this approach, I could now set the properties based on T. But the issue here is that it will have all the properties.
Ex: G<A> will also contain prop2 but it will be of type `never`.
So we need to filter it out, so that intellisense doesn't show this.

```
type NonNeverType<T> = {
  [K in keyof T as T[K] extends never ? never : K]: T[K] & string;
};
```

This filters out properties which are having type never.

This is not so clean solution, but this works for my scenario.